# How to map when having two instances of a class in a second class using fluent nhibernate?

Tags: c#, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I'm doing some research into which of Entity Framework and (fluent) nHibernate is the best fit for a project. And I've stumbled into some mapping problems. I'm hoping someone here can help me out with a quick solution to my problem :)

Here are my entity classes:

```
public abstract class DisplayItem
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Link : DisplayItem
{
    public virtual Node FromNode { get; set; }
    public virtual Node ToNode { get; set; }

    public Link()
    {
    }
}

public class Node : DisplayItem
{
    public virtual IList<Link> LinksFrom { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Link> LinksTo { get; set; }

    public Node()
    {
        LinksFrom = new List<Link>();
        LinksTo = new List<Link>();
    }
}
```

I tried first to use the automatic mapper, but that did not work at all. It did create the database and saved data, but the data was not connected correctly. I think the problem comes because a `Link` contains two instances of `Node`

I then tried manually mapping it, here is the code I used:

```
public class LinkMap : ClassMap
{
    public LinkMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        References(x => x.FromNode);
        References(x => x.ToNode);
    }

}

class NodeMap : ClassMap
{
    public NodeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        HasMany(x => x.LinksFrom)
            .Cascade.All();
        HasMany(x => x.LinksTo)
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I had a guess at the answer. If its not correct, what do you mean by the data is not connected properly? And what inheritance do you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use generics for your lists:

```
public class Node : DisplayItem
{
    public virtual IList<Link> LinksFrom { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Link> LinksTo { get; set; }

    public Node()
    {
        LinksFrom = new List<Link>();
        LinksTo = new List<Link>();
    }
}
```

Secondly, you have inheritance, but you have not stated what style you what to do in the database. If you want to ignore the inheritence, then you need to do this
[Ignoring base-types](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Ignoring_base-types):

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>(cfg)
  .IgnoreBase<Entity>();
```

The default is table-per-subclass.

If you do a table-per-class-hierarchy, be careful of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985213/fluent-nhibernate-entity-hasmany-collections-of-different-subclass-types/4102741#4102741).